# How to Select an option on change event and trigger the other select option to respond?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to populate arrays of object into a form using javascript DOM manipulation. When the user select the size of the drinks the other option will reflect the price according to the change.

Eg. Under Latte > select > small. The price will change to value of 3.

The first one works but the other one "cappuccino" doesn't.

Is there anything wrong with my getMyPrice function?

Hope someone can help me to understand this.

Try selecting all the drinkOption using document.querySelectorAll and do a for loop but it doesn't work.

```
const coffeeMenu = [
 {
    "name":"latte",
    "productVarient": [
        {
            "size": "large",
            "price": 5.9
        },
                {
            "size": "medium",
            "price": 4.5
        },
                {
            "size": "small",
            "price": 3.0
        }
    ]
},
    {
    "name":"cappuccino",
    "productVarient": [
        {
            "size": "large",
            "price": 4.9
        },
                {
            "size": "medium",
            "price": 3.5
        },
                {
            "size": "small",
            "price": 2.0
        }
    ]
 }      
]

window.onload = getMenu();

function getMenu(){
    var myMenu = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(myMenu);
    var myform = document.createElement("form")
    myform.name="myForm"
    myMenu.appendChild(myform);

for(var i = 0; i < coffeeMenu.length; i++){
        let myMenuList = document.createElement('label');
        myMenuList.value = coffeeMenu[i].name;
        myMenuList.innerHTML = coffeeMenu[i].name;

        let drinkSize = document.createElement('select');
        drinkSize.id = "drinkOption";
        drinkSize.onchange = function(){getMyPrice()};
        let sizePrice =  document.createElement('Select');
        sizePrice.id = "priceOption";
        for(var j = 0; j < coffeeMenu[i].productVarient.length; j++){

            let singleSize = document.createElement('option');
            singleSize.className = "getSize";
            singleSize.value = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].size;
            singleSize.innerHTML = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].size;
            drinkSize.appendChild(singleSize);

            let singlePrice = document.createElement('option');
            singlePrice.className ="getPrice"
            singlePrice.value = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].price;
            singlePrice.innerHTML = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].price;
            sizePrice.appendChild(singlePrice);
        };

    myform.appendChild(myMenuList);
    myform.appendChild(drinkSize);
    myform.appendChild(sizePrice);

    };
}

function getMyPrice(){
var myLatte =  document.querySelector('#drinkOption');
var myLatteSize = myLatte.options[myLatte.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
var myLattePrice = document.querySelector('#priceOption');
    switch(myLatteSize){
        case "large":
        document.getElementById('priceOption').selectedIndex = "0";
        break;
        case "medium":
        document.getElementById('priceOption').selectedIndex = "1";
        break;
        case "small":
        document.getElementById('priceOption').selectedIndex = "2";
        break;
    }
};
```

I expected it to work for both but only the "Latte" select option works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there with your code. The only thing that you didn’t account for is that `id`'s have to be unique. So `drinkSize.id = "drinkOption"` will always target the same element, that is why you were getting the bug with `latte` working and `cappuccino` not working.

I fixed the bug for you by assigning `drinkID`’s based on their index in the array.

Please see code below.

```
const coffeeMenu = [
 {
    "name":"latte",
    "productVarient": [
        {
            "size": "large",
            "price": 5.9
        },
                {
            "size": "medium",
            "price": 4.5
        },
                {
            "size": "small",
            "price": 3.0
        }
    ]
},
    {
    "name":"cappuccino",
    "productVarient": [
        {
            "size": "large",
            "price": 4.9
        },
                {
            "size": "medium",
            "price": 3.5
        },
                {
            "size": "small",
            "price": 2.0
        }
    ]
 }
]

window.onload = getMenu();

function getMenu() {
    var myMenu = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(myMenu);
    var myform = document.createElement("form");
    myform.name = "myForm";
    myMenu.appendChild(myform);

    for (var i = 0; i < coffeeMenu.length; i++) {
            let myMenuList = document.createElement('label');
            myMenuList.value = coffeeMenu[i].name;
            myMenuList.innerHTML = coffeeMenu[i].name;

            const drinkID = i;

            let drinkSize = document.createElement('select');
            drinkSize.id = `drinkOption-${drinkID}`;
            drinkSize.onchange = getMyPrice(drinkID);
            let sizePrice =  document.createElement('Select');
            sizePrice.id = `priceOption-${drinkID}`;

            for (var j = 0; j < coffeeMenu[i].productVarient.length; j++) {
                let singleSize = document.createElement('option');
                singleSize.className = "getSize";
                singleSize.value = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].size;
                singleSize.innerHTML = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].size;
                drinkSize.appendChild(singleSize);

                let singlePrice = document.createElement('option');
                singlePrice.className ="getPrice";
                singlePrice.value = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].price;
                singlePrice.innerHTML = coffeeMenu[i].productVarient[j].price;
                sizePrice.appendChild(singlePrice);
            };

        myform.appendChild(myMenuList);
        myform.appendChild(drinkSize);
        myform.appendChild(sizePrice);
    };
}

function getMyPrice(drinkID) {
    return function() {
        var myLatte = document.querySelector(`#drinkOption-${drinkID}`);
        var myLatteSize = myLatte.options[myLatte.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var myLattePrice = document.querySelector(`#priceOption-${drinkID}`);
        switch(myLatteSize) {
            case "large":
                document.querySelector(`#priceOption-${drinkID}`).selectedIndex = "0";
            break;
            case "medium":
                document.querySelector(`#priceOption-${drinkID}`).selectedIndex = "1";
            break;
            case "small":
                document.querySelector(`#priceOption-${drinkID}`).selectedIndex = "2";
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: **Thanks! it work now!** I saw you changing the function to a return function within function. Any reason? May I know why 
document.getElementById(`#priceOption-${drinkID}`).selectedIndex = "0" doesn't work? What is the different of use?

Comment: Glad I could help!
I reformatted the `getMyPrice` function to return a function because it needed to capture the `drinkID` during the time when it was instantiated and return a unique `onchange` method. I know, it all might sound a little confusing, so if you want to understand it a little better - please read about Closures in Javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).
As for the `getElementById` - I was just experimenting and swapped it for `querySelector`. I think, it should still work if you replace it back. I encourage you to experiment too!